# Looking for a theme that takes medical considerations into account

Tags: themes, accessibility

As the title suggests, I am interested in an emacs theme that has been specifically designed for the good of the 24/7 hard-working programmer's eyes.

Notice that this question is not opinion-based; I am asking whether someone has developed a theme that has taken the medical considerations into account and not the personal tastes. There are some articles on the internet that describe the colour schemes, colour contrasts etc. that are least damaging for the eyes.

Comment: See the accessibility-focused and highly customisable light&dark `modus-themes`: https://protesilaos.com/modus-themes. They're on [GNU ELPA](https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/modus-themes.html) and [GNU-devel ELPA](https://elpa.gnu.org/devel/modus-themes.html) and will be built into Emacs 28.

Comment: The question is too broad, IMO. Define "least damaging". (And yes, the question encourages opinion-based answers.)

Comment: I added tag `accessibility`. You should be able to search the two tags to find existing info about themes that might have some accessibility considerations. But the question is too broad. Consider asking a specific question regarding some specific accessibility concern.